# Power and Square Root not working with assert() in C++

Tags: c++, pow, sqrt

I have two functions shown here:
https://pastebin.com/QWQ6yH6u

```
// main() calls both findDistance() and test() correctly so they don't need to be shown.
// Note: This is only a section of the full code as it is the only relevant part.

double findDistance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    double distanceTotal = sqrt( pow( 2, (x2-x1) ) + pow( 2, (y2-y1) )); // This line doesn't work with assert values.
    //double distanceTotal = (x2-x1) + (y2-y1); // This line works with assert values.
    return distanceTotal;
}

void test() {
    assert(findDistance(4, 3, 5, 1) - 2.23607 <= epsilon);
    assert(findDistance(2, 4, 2, 4) <= 1.00);
    assert(findDistance(4, 4, 4, 4) <= 1.00);

    cout << "all tests passed..." << endl;
}
```

The findDistance function is finding the distance between two points (x1, y1), (x2, y2). One line works properly with the assert() values while the one containing square roots and powers does not. What is wrong with line 5?

The code compiles successfully using http://cpp.sh and the output with the current code is:

```
Do you want to run the program? (y/n) y
Program calculates distance between 2 points on a 2D coordinates.
Enter a point in the form (x, y): (3,3)
(x1, y1) = (3.00, 3.00) 
Enter a second point in the form (x, y): (1,1)
(x2, y2) = (1.00, 1.00)
```

I've already checked the following posts:
1. [How to calculate power in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170487/how-to-calculate-power-in-c)
2. [Square root line doesn’t work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47569997/square-root-line-doesn-t-work)
3. [C++ Square Root Function Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782086/c-square-root-function-bug)

Comment: Post code here, not via sites such as pastebin.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I did post the code here too..

Comment: Are you sure you want to compute 2 ^ (delta x)  and 2 ^ (delta y)?

Comment: You can also use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot

Comment: BTW, multiplying, such as `x * x` is more efficient that `pow(x, 2)`.  Also `pow` is floating point.

Comment: Note that `assert` is usually compiled out (does nothing) in optimized/release builds. Only in unoptimized debug builds does it actually do anything.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Are you *sure*? Modern optimizing compilers are pretty smart. I would actually expect them to optimize this to the same thing regardless of what version you write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the wrong use of [`std::pow()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).  This should work much better:

```
double distanceTotal = sqrt( pow( (x2-x1),2 ) + pow( (y2-y1), 2 )); // This line doesn't work with assert values.
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/IhRn9q)

Comment: Oh.. Well I guess the website I learned pow() from was wrong. Thank you very much, that worked!